# Unable to resolve" String was not recognized as a valid DateTime issue" c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

My program was working fine, now I've started receiving

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

errors which I can't seem to get around. I've have searched high and low for a solution, but nothing fixes the problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"../Debug/");
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");

    Dictionary<FileInfo, DateTime> filesWithDueDate = new Dictionary<FileInfo, DateTime>();

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        string dueDate = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}");
        Match mat = regex.Match(dueDate);

        // Error happens here //
        DateTime duedate = Convert.ToDateTime(mat.ToString());

        filesWithDueDate.Add(file, duedate);
    }

    var sortedFiles = filesWithDueDate.OrderBy(a => a.Value).Select(b => b.Key.Name).ToArray();

    listBox1.Items.AddRange(sortedFiles);
}
```

Comment: put a breakpoint on that line and inspect of the value of mat

Comment: Try specifying the culture

Comment: whats the value of duedate/mat before the error occurs

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.Parse()` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime()`? This is generally a bit more lenient in terms of formatting.

Comment: `15/04/2016` will match your regex, but may or may not (according to culture) define a valid date.

Comment: I was once driven nuts by date parse failures that hit only one machine.  I finally found out the user had changed their date display to dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: @galacticfan DateTime.Parse will throw an error on invalid. You would need DateTIme.TryParse() then handle the out if its success, handle if it fails.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the TryParse pattern and throw a good exception when it fails

```
DateTime dateValue;
bool tryParseAttempt = DateTime.TryParse(mat.ToString(), out dateValue);
if(!tryParseAttempt)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Cannot parse value to DateTime.  '{0}'", mat.ToString());
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or this:


    DateTime dateValue;            
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(mat, out dateValue))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Cannot parse value to DateTime.  '{0}'", mat));
    }

Comment: I'm usually more verbose when trying to teach the concept (to show clearly what is going on).

Comment: That's fair enough. I forget sometimes it's needed for the sake of illustration versus language function.

Answer (score 0):

Not a programming issue it would seem, I've just restarted my machine and it all seems to be working as expected.... Thanks everyone for your advice though..

Comment: That's great.  But still implementing the TryParse pattern would be prudent.

Comment: Agreed. Not implementing a try/parse, while for the moment works, will have unexpected results should it not receive a valid datetime string.

Answer (score 0):

Modification to @GranadaCoder answer

Try it like this:

Or this:

```
DateTime dateValue;            
if (!DateTime.TryParse(mat, out dateValue))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Cannot parse value to DateTime.  '{0}'", mat));
}
```

The declared extra bool is unnecessary as it returns a true/false already. Likewise, in a format string, if you are using string.Format, the args will already be .ToString(), so no need to call mat.ToString() unless specifying the formatting of the date/time.